AWS lambda to Azure functions
I have a function in AWS lambda which is connected with AWS API gateway, no what I want to do is to move this setup to Azure, such that I want my function in Azure functions app and connect it with Azure API management so that I can use this API and use a GET request from postman to get the desired output.
I tried creating an HTTP trigger and then changing the code inside the function but it never worked I tried using Azure CLI to push the Python file but it was still not successful.

please share your function code

I have created a .Net6 Http triggered function which has the below code.
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace _78441856
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("HttpTriggeredFunction")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}


Then, I published this function to function app using visual studio.
In order to link the function app to APIM, you can use the below option present in function app.




You can also link the function app in APIM instance.



Once it is linked, you will be able to see the operations.


To Test it in postman, you need to pass ocp-apim-subscription-key key in the request header.
Fetch the request URL from the Test menu.



